# Hc-05 android interfacing

Tags: android, bluetooth

The sample BluetoothChat app works fine when I communicate between 2 devices but when I try to connect with HC-05 bluetooth module I am unable to even connect with this. Do I have to edit my code and any suggestions could be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to HC-05 you must use a correct UUID. In the sample BluetoothChat application replace its current value in `BluetoothChatService` class with `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` (that is a default one for SPP - Synchronous Serial Port used by HC-05 as well).